# Palindrome with recursion; index out of bound

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether a string variable is a palindrome or not. 
I can't find the reason this code throws `IndexOutOfBoundException`. I've tried to use examples so as to follow the result, but I still can't see where the exception is from.

```
public static boolean palindrome(String s) {
    if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length() - 1)) {
        if (s.length() > 2) {       
            StdOut.print(s.substring(1, s.length() - 2));
            palindrome(s.substring(1, s.length() - 2));
        } else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the exception. It tells you exactly in which line it happens and what the invalid index value is.

Comment: Another problem I haven't seen mentioned is that you ignore the result of the recursive call - I believe you wish to return this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String s)
{
    if (s.length() < 2)
        return true;
    if (s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(s.length()-1))
        return false;
    return palindrome(s.substring(1,s.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: `charAt(0)` should be `s.charAt(0)`.

Comment: @bcsb1001: Yep, must have slipped out during the copy-paste from the question. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me understand the sequence of conditions.

Answer (score 4):

`palindrome` can end up calling itself with an empty string. When that happens, the first line with give an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `s.charAt(0)`.

P.S. On closer inspection, the bounds in the `substring` calls are also incorrect: since the end index is *exclusive*, the second argument should be `s.length() - 1`. You'll need to fix that too.

Comment: actually the string should be a least 1 char

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't undertand the first part of  what you said, yes, the last call will be s.charAt(0), but the condition: s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length() - 1) can be checked:

Answer (score 1):

Your substring is wrong. You are removing an extra character from the end.

```
public static boolean palindrome(String s) {
    if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length() - 1)) {
        if (s.length() > 2) {       
            StdOut.print(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
            palindrome(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
        } else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

1. As noted, the `substring` call is wrong - the `endIndex` is exclusive, so you should end at `s.length() - 1)`
2. You are calling `palindrome`, and then moving on with the function, eventually returning `false` - instead, you should **return** the result of `palindrome` applied on the substring:

So, after taking both these mistakes in to considetation, the method should read as follows:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String s) {
    if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length() - 1)) {
        if (s.length() > 2) {
            // note the return and the corrected substring
            return palindrome(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
        } else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```